# Setting permissions in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called `admin_permissions` with the following columns:

1. sequence
2. page_name
3. level_user
4. level_admin
5. level_support
6. level_accounts

the last 4 columns are the different levels

I have this code which checks the permissions:

```
$permission_sql="SELECT * from admin_permissions where page_name = '".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."' ";
$permission_rs=mysql_query($permission_sql,$conn);
if(mysql_num_rows($permission_rs) == 0)
{
    echo '<h2 align="center">An Error has occurred!</h2>';
    exit();
}
else
{
    $permission_result=mysql_fetch_array($permission_rs);
    if($usertype_user != $permission_result["level_user"] or 
    $usertype_support != $permission_result["level_support"] or 
    $usertype_admin != $permission_result["level_admin"] or 
    $usertype_accounts != $permission_result["level_accounts"])
    {
        echo '<h2 align="center">Access Denied</h2>';
        echo '<h2 align="center">Please contact your administrator quoting \'Permission Error\' and number \''.$permission_result["sequence"].'\'</h2>';
        exit();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

the `$usertype_`... either equal '' or 'yes' and the database results either equal '' or 'yes'

the user i am logged in as, has `$permission_result["level_admin"]` equal to yes so the above if statement should be false but its not, its saying its true

how can i get the above code to work

**P.S. I am not worried about SQL Injection on this particular code*

Comment: @cHao Unfortunately a very large amount of PHP tutorials still use `mysql_*` to teach Python+MySQL programming. I'd be very glad if somebody wrote one that uses PDO or MySQLi, but I'm not aware of the existence of one yet.

Comment: PHP.net has written many for people Timothy. `one` is an understatement. What can be more easily explained than this http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0):

please remove 'or' try with ||, for checking or condition use the symbol "||" , for checking and condition use "&&"

```
$permission_sql="SELECT * from admin_permissions where page_name = '".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."' ";
$permission_rs=mysql_query($permission_sql,$conn);
if(mysql_num_rows($permission_rs) == 0)
{
    echo '<h2 align="center">An Error has occurred!</h2>';
    exit();
}
else
{
    $permission_result=mysql_fetch_array($permission_rs);
    if(($usertype_user != $permission_result["level_user"]) || 
    ($usertype_support != $permission_result["level_support"])|| 
    ($usertype_admin != $permission_result["level_admin"])|| 
    ($usertype_accounts != $permission_result["level_accounts"]))
    {
        echo '<h2 align="center">Access Denied</h2>';
        echo '<h2 align="center">Please contact your administrator quoting \'Permission Error\' and number \''.$permission_result["sequence"].'\'</h2>';
        exit();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried using || for 'or' but the statement is still returning true even though it should be false. i am receiving the error when i shouldnt be

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
if($usertype_user != $permission_result["level_user"] or 
$usertype_support != $permission_result["level_support"] or 
$usertype_admin != $permission_result["level_admin"] or 
$usertype_accounts != $permission_result["level_accounts"])
```

is true if at least one of these permissions doesn't match, it is false only if all these permissions match. In your case, at least one of user, support, admin, accounts don't match level_user, level_support, level_admin, level_accounts, so check it: you may have admin match (yes==yes or ''==''), but you might be missing something else.

You probably want something like this:

```
if(
  ($permission_result["level_user"] and $usertype_user!='yes') or
  ($permission_result["level_support"] and $usertype_support!='yes') or
  ($permission_result["level_admin"] and $usertype_admin!='yes') or
  ($permission_result["level_account"] and $usertype_accounts!='yes')
)
```

**Notes**

Have a look at [type jugling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in php: if you have `" "` instead of `""` somewhere, it is evaluated as `true`

The difference between `or` and `||` or `and` and `&&` is only in precedence, see [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), doesn't matter in this case.

I'm not sure if `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` has to be url encoded; to be sure, you may use `mysql_real_escape_string` on it - or better, as the comments complain about mysql_* deprecation, `mysqli_real_escape_string` - or, if you don't use some exotic charset, just `addslashes`.

Comment: my database looks like - http://postimg.org/image/z3h483c59/ - and the user i am logged in as has level_user = '' / level_admin = '' / level_support = '' / level_accounts = '' so they should not have access to this page at all however they do

Comment: so try `var_dump($permission_result, $usertype_user, $usertype_support, $usertype_admin, $usertype_accounts);`, check the values and tell me if there is something against logic